# how to create pop up window in python spyder, that can call out dataframe that connected with excel for the data

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

im confused because i need to run tkinter, that could read my dataframe, and i want it so it can call it in my pop up window by only typing the code and clicking the button to call it out. example: the button's name is "Mean value", and there's an input box to write the code, for example i type "cgk ams", then i click the button, it will print and show me the result or the mean value of "cgk ams", the dataframe in my python connected to excel, so it calculating the value from the excel data.[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkJrF.png)

for example that's the dataframe, and it's not only one, there are 5/6 dataframe like that cause each contains different info but same models, and the dataframes import data from excel.

i really need help for this. only to make the tkinter work as what i said above

Answer (score 0):

Well, though not *exactly* TKinter, you could use [PySimpleGui](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which would make the whole popup significantly easier. In fact, one of the first PySimpleGUI examples sounds a lot like what you're looking for:

*NOTE*: I'm taking the cheap way out here and just copying the example directly.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('DarkAmber')   # Add a touch of color
# All the stuff inside your window.
layout = [  [sg.Text('Some text on Row 1')],
            [sg.Text('Enter something on Row 2'), sg.InputText()],
            [sg.Button('Ok'), sg.Button('Cancel')] ]

# Create the Window
window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)
# Event Loop to process "events" and get the "values" of the inputs
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel': # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break
    print('You entered ', values[0])

window.close()
```

[image: PySimpleGUI Example]

From there, you could pretty easily modify it to accept other inputs if you needed, or change the layout/button-text/etc. You could also make another popup that would display other information if you wanted.

You should be able to install PySimpleGUI quite easily since it's on PyPI:
https://pypi.org/project/PySimpleGUI/

**EDIT**

I think I should be clear, PySimpleGUI *does* use TKinter under the hood, but it provides a really clean way to interface with the TK core functionality, and doesn't dive off into the weeds and intricacies of TK. Still, it *is* using TK tooling.

Comment: Omg, can I use "if else" and "print" to get the value of what I'm looking for? Because as I said before, there are 5/6 dataframe formula to get average (like in the photo) and I need them to appear when I called them with a specific code. Thanks for your answer!